# Iterate array non-sequentially

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am working with an array of objects (tweets) and I only want to iterate over a certain number of those objects on each page load.  Where the last count stopped iterating will be saved and started there again on the next page load.  This is where I'm stuck.

```
var obj1 = [{
  "name": "trai"
}, {
  "name": "beth"
}, {
  "name": "taylor"
}, {
  "name": "trace"
}, {
  "name": "dad"
}, {
  "name": "elaine"
}];

var i = 5;  //last index.  will be updated and retrieved in browser storage
var num = 2;  //number to iterate

for (var count = 0; count < num; count++) {
    $('body').append('<div>' + obj1[i].name + '</div>');
    if (i >= obj1.length) {
        i = 0;
    }
    else {i++;}
}
```

Comment: It's not clear from your question which aspect of the problem you're having difficulty solving. What is happening that doesn't match what you expected/wanted to happen?

Comment: @Jamiec Not a different technology. Just localStorage.

Comment: @Jamiec they do if I save them and set them from session storage

Comment: @Jamiec - the comment in the code indicates the OP is persisting `i` in browser storage (presumably localStorage) so that shouldn't be an issue here.

Comment: @RJM It seems as I am stuck in a loop...using jsfiddle to test.  I'll try locally.

Comment: I just had a misunderstanding of how the object length was counted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a mistake in how I determined obj1.length was counted.  I thought if you started counting from zero the length would be 5, but the length is 6.  Fixed it by accounting for the correct length of the object.

```
var obj1 = [{
  "name": "trai"
}, {
  "name": "beth"
}, {
  "name": "taylor"
}, {
  "name": "trace"
}, {
  "name": "dad"
}, {
  "name": "elaine"
}];

var i = 5;  //last index.  will be updated and retrieved in browser storage
var num = 2;  //number to iterate
var lngth = obj1.length -1;  //accounted for length here
for (var count = 0; count < num; count++) {
    $('body').append('<div>' + obj1[i].name + '</div>');

    if (i == lngth) {
        i = 0;
    }
    else {i++;}
}
```

Results in:
elaine
trai

Answer (score 0):

Why not just set the start index accordingly?

```
for (var count = i; (count < i + num) && (count < obj1.length); count++) {
    $('body').append('<div>' + obj1[count].name + '</div>');
}

if(i + num >= obj1.length) {
    i = 0;
} else {
    i += num;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On every page, you need to store your ending counter in localStorage. And on every page, you need to check if there is already a valid value for your counter in localStorage. If there is not, you can assume this is the first time and start from 0 ( or whatever you prefer ).

```
var obj1 = [{
  "name": "trai"
}, {
  "name": "beth"
}, {
  "name": "taylor"
}, {
  "name": "trace"
}, {
  "name": "dad"
}, {
  "name": "elaine"
}];

var i = 0;  //last index.  will be updated and retrieved in browser storage
if( typeof localStorage.getItem("lastCounter") != "undefined" )
{
  i = parseInt( localStorage.getItem("lastCounter") ) || 0;
}

var num = 2;  //number to iterate

for (var count = 0; count < num; count++) {
    $('body').append('<div>' + obj1[i].name + '</div>');
    if (i >= obj1.length) {
        i = 0;
    }
    else {i++;}
}
localStorage.setItem("lastCounter", i );
```